# Print formatted string using a std::vector (of variable size)

Tags: c++builder

I use the Magento 2 REST API and want to handle errors that get thrown in C++.

Example error response:

```
{
  "message": "Could not save category: %1",
  "parameters": [
    "URL key for specified store already exists."
  ]
}
```

I can retrieve both of these into a String and std::vector which leaves me with the question:

**How am I able to return a String that is formatted by filling the placeholders?**

With a fixed size, I could do something along the lines of this

```
char* buffer = new char[200];
String message = "Could not save category: %1";
std::vector<String> parameters = {"URL key for specified store already exists."};

String result = sprintf(buffer,message.c_str(),parameters[0]);
```

But, alas, I do not know the size beforehand.

How should I go about doing this? Are there stl functions that could help,  should I be using self-written templates(no experience with this), can I convert the std::vector to a va_list, or are there other solutions?

Comment: Whoops! Good eye, I've added a pointer. And I mean to add more elements through a loop, but I've left it a 1 element for simplicity's sake.

Comment: You can use the [Format](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20499) function in C++ Builder.

Comment: @Ron That's a) nonstandard, and b) requires expanding the params in the callsite, which is pretty hard with `std::vector`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Off course it is. Hence the C++ Builder tag only after my edit. You've missed the `String` type which is Delphi / C++Builder specific. Hence my comment. Nothing in the question relates to portable C++.

Comment: @Ron oops, my bad, Missed that. Nevermind.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Np.

Comment: Thanks both, I will definitely try the Format function, and try to use TVarRec instead of std::vector. I don't have a lot of time left today, so that will probably be an exercise for tomorrow.

Comment: It would be very difficult to use `Format()` and `sprintf()` (FYI, `String` has its own `(s)printf()` methods, don't use the C functions of the same names) with variable-length parameters that are not known until runtime. A simple search-and-replace loop would be better

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I didn't notice this asks for a C++ dialect and not Standard C++. Leaving it for now, might be of use for other people.

---

Nothing standard exists that will do that automatically. That being said, if your interpolation format is just `%<number>` it might be easy enough to write:

```
string message = "Could not save category: %1";
std::vector<string> parameters = {"URL key for specified store already exists."};

for (size_t i = 0; i < parameters.size(); ++i) {
    const auto interp = "%" + std::to_string(i+1);
    const size_t pos = message.find(interp);

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        message.replace(pos, interp.size(), parameters[i]);
}
```

This will put the result in the `message` string. Of course this implementation is rather limited and not particularly efficient, but again, doing this properly requires a library-sized solution, not SO-answer-sized one.

[**live version**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a52188d85875cc8).